# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular
Other Binding is working fine but $https call is not working 
I got error like this when I call http call

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**
My Script Code is

```
(function(angular) {
   var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
   myApp.controller('myTestController', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.firstName = "Test";
     $http.get("Students/GetStudents").success(function(response) {
       $scope.firstName = response;
     });
   });
 })(window.angular);
```

My API Controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetStudents() {
    return "My Value";
}
```

Comment: have you verified the url/resource path is correct?

Comment: I have One Folder as Controllers and in that i have api controller as StudentsController.  when i put this url in browser it display error like:  The resource cannot be found.

Comment: try creating a .json file with some content, and call it from $http.get, instead of trying to call the controller

Comment: Hi when i call this method of same controller it's working [ResponseType(typeof(Student))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetStudent(int id)
        {
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(student);
        }                                sorry for poor editing

Comment: Don't paste code into a comment. [Edit your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28539659/edit)

Answer (score 0):

In Api Controller:

    `[HttpGet]
    [Route("getStudents")]
    public string GetStudents() {
        return "My Value";
    }`

And in angular: 
change "Students/GetStudents" for "Students/getStudents"